# Google Drive API files.list not refreshing

Tags: java, google-drive-api, file-listing

I have a feeling this is a duplicate question, but I can't find the solution.  I am making a simple Google Drive API files.list call in java (just running it in Eclipse).  It works fine.  But when I change my Drive (delete a file, etc), the API call is still showing old data.  I've used the "try it out" function in the reference documentation and get the same result.
Is there a "force refresh" type of thing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no "force refresh" because none of the information is being cached. It's all live data.

There is not enough information in your question to answer your problem, but two things to check out ...

1. if you trash a file, it is simply marked as trashed. Therefore it will still be retrieved unless you add trashed=false to your files.list
2. There are some meta data changes which take a short while (a few seconds only) to propagate. Therefore if you change a property and immediately query it, you might not see the changes straight away.